# Cant get table to update, delete and add with an extra code

Tags: php

So What Im trying to do is have the user add a code to a form, and fill the form out, A to add to the table, D to delete, U to update... The delete isnt working, neither is the insert, is it my logic? also I want to print the table only once, and sometimes it does it twice... any advice?

```
$Code=$_POST["Code"];

if ($Code == "A") 
    {
$sql = "INSERT INTO movieDATA values ('$idno', '$Name', '$Genre', '$Starring', '$Year', '$BoxOffice')";
$result= mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$showresult = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from movieDATA") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($link));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showresult))
   {
    echo ("<br> ID = ". $row["IDNO"] . "<br> NAME =  " . $row["Name"] . "<br>");
    echo("Genre = " . $row["Genre"] . "<br> Starring = " . $row["Starring"] . "<br>");
    echo("Year = " . $row["Year"] . "<br> Box Office = " . $row["BoxOffice"] . "<br>");
   }

}
elseif ($Code == "D")
{
$sql = "DELETE FROM movieDATA WHERE IDNO = '$idno'";
$result= mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$showresult = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from movieDATA") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($link));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showresult))
   {
    echo ("<br> ID = ". $row["IDNO"] . "<br> NAME =  " . $row["Name"] . "<br>");
    echo("Genre = " . $row["Genre"] . "<br> Starring = " . $row["Starring"] . "<br>");
    echo("Year = " . $row["Year"] . "<br> Box Office = " . $row["BoxOffice"] . "<br>");
   }

}

elseif ($Code == "U")
{
$sql = "UPDATE movieDATA SET Name = '$Name', Genre = '$Genre', Starring = '$Starring', Year = '$Year', BoxOffice = '$BoxOffice' where IDNO = '$idno'";
$result= mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$showresult = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from movieDATA") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($link));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showresult))
   {
    echo ("<br> ID = ". $row["IDNO"] . "<br> NAME =  " . $row["Name"] . "<br>");
    echo("Genre = " . $row["Genre"] . "<br> Starring = " . $row["Starring"] . "<br>");
    echo("Year = " . $row["Year"] . "<br> Box Office = " . $row["BoxOffice"] . "<br>");
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Replace your `=` in the if statements with `==`, like this: `if ($code == "D")`.

Comment: On a side note you could probably lose 2/3 of this script by just changing the sql statement and the parameters (you should not be injecting the variables into the statement like you are doing) and leaving the rest. You have a lot of duplication.

Comment: how can I do that? I know I could be doing just one print of the table but I couldnt get it to work

Comment: I would make a couple functions to accomplish all this,

Comment: Eduardo I tried that and it didnt work

Comment: Also this is homework, I have not learned functions yet, so I cant use them

Comment: I could show you but the example would be using PDO, I am more familiar with that database library. @EduardoGalván is right, you have to definitely have `==`

Comment: What about `switch()`? That would be better as an alternative.

Comment: fixed, i got a variable name wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110432/discussion-between-fagner-schuindt-caetano-and-rasclatt).